# Calling API's In componentDidMount or in the on click of the button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to the `react-redux`. Here, I have a button, which is like ,

```
<button className="btn btn-primary fetchBtnSize"
            disabled={this.state.disableFetchQuestion}
            onClick={() => this.fetchQuestions()}>
            Fetch Questions
                </button>
        </div >
```

Now, In this method

```
fetchQuestions() {   this.props.fetchQuestions(result); }
```

Now In my action ,

```
export function fetchQuestions(arrayOfQuesObjs) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: REQUEST_INITIATED
        });
        post(FETCH_QUESTIONS_URL, arrayOfQuesObjs)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    dispatch({
                        type: REQUEST_SUCCESSED,
                    });
                    history.push('/quiz-questions');
                    dispatch({
                        type: FETCHING_QUESTIONS_SUCCESS,
                        data: response.payload,
                    })
                }
                else {
                    dispatch({
                        type: REQUEST_SUCCESSED
                    });
                    toastr.error(response.status.message);
                    dispatch({
                        type: FAILED_QUESTIONS_FETCHING,
                        data: response.status,
                    });
                    if (response.status === 401) {
                        toastr.error("Please login again");
                        localStorage.clear();
                        history.push('/');
                    }
                }
            })
    }
}
```

So, here After success only I am redirecting the user to the `quiz-questions page`.

Now, on this I am rendering one component .

Now, What happens is that when user clicks on the reload page of the `quiz-questions` that time this data which was fetched from the server gets lost . because the state gets cleared.
Now, what I did was like ,

```
on history.push({ pathName: '/quiz-questions', state : { data: 1, isfetch: true   }})
```

so, that when I click on reload button that time I will take that data from the `props.location.state.data`

and then

```
componentDidMount() { this.props.fetchQuestions(props.location.state.data);  }
```

Now, Here,what is happening,On click of the `button` If I remove the api call and redirect user to the `/quiz-questions` that time if the api gets faild then user should be at `previous page only`

So, I am not understanding where to call this `API`. If I keep it on both places then `it will call two times`. SO, How can I resolve this ?

Comment: btw in order to persist store state during page reload you should use something like https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

Answer (score 0):

In no case data in redux store persists after reload. You need to handle this case logically. Take a look at [this](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/09/16/react-redux-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example) tutorial. You should manage the flow of your data in this way.

For a brief, any data that you need on multiple routes even after reloading should be fetched in App (parent component) Component in `componentDidMount()` lifecycle hook. Also, if possible, try `history.push()` always, as it does not lead to loss of data on route change. Hope that helps, good luck!

Comment: Hey, I am using the history.push thing. Now, If I copy the link and paste it in the new tab of the same browser that time in the constructor it gives me undefined as a state object

Comment: @ganeshkaspate your redux store will only be usable in the same tab. Moreover, if you copy and paste it in new tab, that means you are reloading and initially the state would be undefined (if you haven't already defined something). If you want to use something that is available on all the tabs in same browser, redux is not the solution for it. You should use `session` or `cookies` or `localStorage`.

Comment: okay, so now here what is happening is that in my code , there I am using that  in the componentDidMount , so here, I added one check that if(this.props.data) then only call the method. But what happens is when we go from button there this method gets called two times.

Comment: Because, on click of button it calls an api and then redirect user to the page there in did mount I am using the reducer state , where it has the response of the previous call, but that point of time it does not have that data, so it calls again in did mount.

Comment: Are you fetching data in main App Component or some other component?? @ganeshkaspate